# Manipulando input date

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um **input** do tipo **date**, eu gostaria de manipular este input, pois quando o mesmo é executado no iOS(phonegap app) ele se torna um **combo**, assim quando executo um evento de **onChange**, haveria alguma forma de validar se houve o **change** e qual ele parou, ao invés de "ouvir" cada troca de valor e executar minha função para cada troca?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola pode ter uma forma mais simples, mas essa pode funcionar. Voce pode adicionar e remover uma classe para saber se o usuario tocou ou nao.

```
  function verificarFuncao(){

      $('#input').toggleClass('clicado');

      if(('#input').hasClass('clicado')){
             console.log('foi clicado');
      }      
  }
```